# Create new object from array of keys

Tags: typescript

I need to create an object composed of the picked object properties.

```js
export function pick<
  KeyType extends string | symbol,
  KeysToPick extends KeyType[] | ReadonlyArray<KeyType>,
  ObjectToPickFrom extends Record<KeyType, any>,
  TargetObject extends { [key in KeyType]: ObjectToPickFrom[key] },
>(record: ObjectToPickFrom, keys: KeysToPick, defineMissing: false): TargetObject;
export function pick<
  KeyType extends string | symbol,
  KeysToPick extends KeyType[] | ReadonlyArray<KeyType>,
  ObjectToPickFrom extends Record<KeyType, any>,
  TargetObject extends { [key in KeyType]: ObjectToPickFrom[key] | undefined },
>(record: ObjectToPickFrom, keys: KeysToPick, defineMissing: true): TargetObject;
export function pick<
  KeyType extends string | symbol,
  KeysToPick extends KeyType[] | ReadonlyArray<KeyType>,
  ObjectToPickFrom extends Record<KeyType, any>,
  TargetObject extends { [key in KeyType]: ObjectToPickFrom[key] | undefined },
>(record: ObjectToPickFrom, keys: KeysToPick, defineMissing?: boolean): TargetObject {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    keys
      .map((key: string | symbol) => {
        if (record.hasOwnProperty(key) && [key, record[key]]) {
          return [key, record[key]];
        }
        if (defineMissing) {
          return [key, undefined];
        }
        return undefined;
      })
      .filter((entry: [Key: ObjectToPickFrom[KeyType] | undefined]) => {
        return entry;
      }),
  );
}
```

```js
const keyAsString = "alpha";
const keyAsSymbol = "beta";
const record = {
  [keyAsString]: true,
  [keyAsSymbol]: false,
  extra: null,
};
const keys = [keyAsString, keyAsSymbol, "missing"];
const object = pick(record, keys, true);
console.dir(object);
```

Right now I missing exact return type as I can't figure out how to Pick<Type, Keys> correctly. I expanded the types a bit to make it clear what I want to achieve. Return Object generic should have Keys generic as property key not string or symbol.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend **not** using the name `Object` for a type parameter, as it's a built-in type (in TypeScript) and function (in JavaScript). (In fact, you're using a method on the function, `fromEntries`, in the code!) Here's a TypeScript playground link with that type parameter's name changed to `TargetObject`: https://tsplay.dev/WJyZgm

Comment: Similarly, using `Pick` in `{ [Pick in Key]: Instance[Pick] | undefined }` is confusing, given the pre-existing utility type called `Pick`.